# Is there a way to check if entry is selected in relationship?

Tags: craft3, relations

This project has a lot of user stuff. I need to display display different sections based on if the current user is in a field.

Is there a better/faster way than looping through and checking if every user matched the current user?

```
{% for approve in entry.docsApprovedBy.all() %}
   {% if approve.id == currentUser.id %}...{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the docs about [relations](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html#the-relatedto-parameter)

```
relatedEntries = craft.entries.relatedTo({targetElement: currentUser, field: 'docsApprovedBy'}).all()
```

Comment: That's still doing an additional query which I was trying to avoid. I already have the entry. I was hoping for something like 'if user.id in entry.docsApprovedBy'. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then you can do `if currentUser.id in entry.field.ids()` but you can't do it without an additional query.

Comment: Love it! Since I already have entry this is exactly what i wanted! Thanks